# How to show only selected rows when a button is clicked in jquery?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery with the data table plugin. Code example is given below.
I want to show only the selected rows when the button is clicked. 
What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Data Table Example</title>

 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
 <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.2/css/select.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>


<div class="container">

 <div class="row text-right">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="selected"> Show only Selected </button>
 </div>


<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>

   
  </tbody>
 </table>

</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.27/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.27/vfs_fonts.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.2/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
     // "info": false,
     "searching": false,
     "bLengthChange": false,

        columnDefs: [ {
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets:   0
        } ],
        select: {
            style:    'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    } );


    $("#selected").on('click', function(){
  

    });


} );

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9):

[According to the author of jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/36877/is-there-a-way-to-show-only-selected-rows#Comment_97653) there is no simple way to do it.

You need to use custom search function and modify some other initialization options.

See the example below for code and demonstration.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Data Table Example</title>

 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
 <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.2/css/select.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>


<div class="container">

 <div class="row text-right">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-show-selected"> Show only Selected</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-show-all"> Show All</button>    
 </div>


<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>

   
  </tbody>
 </table>

</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.27/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.27/vfs_fonts.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.2/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'trp',
        columnDefs: [ {
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets:   0
        } ],
        select: {
            style:    'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    } );


    $("#btn-show-selected").on('click', function(){
      $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
            function (settings, data, dataIndex){             
                return ($(table.row(dataIndex).node()).hasClass('selected')) ? true : false;
            }
        );
          
        table.draw();
          
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
    });

    $("#btn-show-all").on('click', function(){
        table.draw();
    });
} );

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gyrocode.com you seem to have missed your piece of the code. Can you please show me your solution?

Comment: Shameless Plug: Gyrocode.com, you seem to have good knowledge of the data table plugin(I saw your blog). I have checked most of the video tutorial websites online, I could not find any for the data table plugin. Why dont you make one course or series and put it on websites like lynda.com, pluralsight or udemy?? you make money and community gets knowledge. 
Do you like the idea?

Comment: @ChetanGanji, that sounds like fun, I will check out the sites you've mentioned. Thanks for the reference.